# Is she speaking proper Cockney (or whatever it is she's imitating)?

Tags: pronunciation, dialects

[image: Marlene Dietrich]

At one point in *Witness for the Prosecution*, Marlene Dietrich's character is at some pains impersonating a guttersnipe. I've been told that the actress spent quite some time working on her accent for this scene. The acting part is well-nigh impeccable (as usual with Dietrich). It's the accent I'm not so sure about. It does sound like a plausible imitation, but is it a little off? And if so, how? Please enlighten me.

This clip contains the scene. Dietrich she starts talking at the 2:27 mark:

https://youtu.be/sjkWibjhpIo&t=2m27s

Comment: Seems fishy to me...

Comment: @michael_timofeev: "I know not 'seems'." Call me an extremist, but I do need a definite detailed answer here.

Comment: Quoting Hamlet at me are we?

Comment: @michael_timofeev: Erudite fellas, aren't we?

Comment: Well, I hope you get an answer before the authorities shut down your question as primarily opinion based.

Comment: @michael_timofeev: All questions are opinion based. As are all answers. It's all predicated on the number of mystagogues (or hierophants, I can never remember which is which) sharing the opinion. Phlogiston was once viewed as a factual entity too, just like evolution and the Big Bang are today.

Comment: @michael_timofeev: I certainly would be. I can't in all honesty vouch for the others. They're flaky.

Comment: Ok, so it is somewhat off, but I am not willing to go through it and do the  work. A couple of times, she even pronounces a few words as in AmE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

She is attempting (very badly) to imitate a Cockney accent. She has it in very short snatches but generally it is obvious to any Londoner (or any British person) that she is a long way away from the real thing. She is clearly coming at it from her Germanic natural tongue. Even so, she proably does a better job than Dick Van Dyke in *Mary Poppins*.

For a dramatic representation of Cockney - try [Marni Nixon as Audrey Hepburn's singing voice in *My Fair Lady*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cl4V700ejTI)

Whilst 1000 times more authentic than the OP's example, even she doesn't have it exactly.

Comment: I listened to it and it's quite lacking...she's an amazing actress, nevertheless.

Comment: Thank you. I suspected it was something like that. Pride is one of the deadly seven sins: she should have asked to be dubbed in that scene. As for Audrey, she's gorgeous and all, never mind a native speaker, but I don't buy it. She articulates like mad, and her tones are soul-wrenchingly pure. Cute, but trying too hard (as she does when she kicks that basket: a grasshopper trying to imitate Ronaldo).

Comment: Oh, and, by the way, I just looked it up: it's Marni Nixon singing. Same thing, though.

Comment: @Ricky You are quite right. But even Marni Nixon doesn't get it completely right. But as she makes a one-thousand times better fist of imitating the accent, and Audrey is very lovely with it, I thought it worth including. I will try and find you a genuine Cockney.

Comment: @Ricky Of course if you want a really good example of what a Cockney accent ISN'T, then try Dick Van Dyke in *Mary Poppins*.

Comment: Lovely video, perhaps the girls go slightly over the top but very illustrative nonetheless.

Comment: @WS2: Thanks, I appreciate that. (According to Enry Iggins, there's like 200 different Cockney dialects, though. Well. Anything will do at this point. Recently I watched a BBC production of _The Devil's Disciple_. It was pathetic. They took a great play and turned it into a tedious poorly acted farce. The only good point was all of those Yankees spoke BBC British with the occasional foray into Cockney (to my ear, anyway). That was hilarious, I couldn't stop giggling).

Comment: @WS2: Decidedly not bad. Thank you!

Comment: Try [this series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pVLKR8oH-T4) for real Cockney

Comment: @frank that's brilliant. Why didn't I think of Steptoe? I thought of Alf Garnet but opted out of airing his racism. Why don't you edit my answer to include Steptoe?

Comment: @frank Why don't you provide it as an answer? I will up-vote it.

Comment: Your video link is dead. I will edit it out.